# Dropzone.js delay posting to the server but allow uploading to begin

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

Is it possible to process files with Dropzone, **but** wait until a button is clicked to post them to server code?

I have tried`autoProcessQueue = false`, however this doesn't start the uploading, I would like to start the process (so my users don't have to wait), but not have dropzone.js call the url straight away.

```
    $(".dropzone.song-image").each(function (i) {
        $(this).dropzone({
            url: $(this).data().url,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            maxFilesize: 20,
            maxFiles: 1,
            acceptedFiles: "image/*",
            dictDefaultMessage: "Add cover image",
            dictInvalidFileType: "Only images are accepted",
            thumbnailWidth: 330,
            thumbnailHeight: 330,
            init: function (file) {
                this.on("thumbnail", function (file, dataUrl) {
                    $(".dropzone.song-image .dz-image").last().find("img").attr({ width: "100%", height: "100%" });
                });
                this.on("success", function (file, response) {
                    $(this.element).siblings("input[type=hidden]").val(response.imageBytes);
                    file.previewElement.classList.add("dz-success");
                    $(".dropzone.song-image .dz-image").css({ "width": "100%", "height": "auto" });
                });
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the source code, and `xhr.Send(form);` (posting to the server of your url) is sent immediately after the files have been processed and then the upload begins.

So, unless someone knows any better than me, I don't think it's possible without changing Dropzone.js source code (or even at all?) which I obviously don't want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here how i implement delayed uploading (initiated by click on any button, for an example):

Dropzone implementation

```
var count = 0;
var addedFilesHash = {};
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#file_upload-form", {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFilesize: 5, // MB
    parallelUploads: 5,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,.xlsx,.xls,.pdf,.doc,.docx",
    maxFiles: 10,
    init: function() {
        this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
            // delete from our dict removed file
            delete addedFilesHash[file];
        });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        var _id = count++;
        file._id = _id;
        addedFilesHash[_id] = done;
    }
});
```

Somewhere else

```
    // get all uploaded files in array
    var addedFiles = Object.keys(addedFilesHash);
    // iterate them
    for (var i = 0; i< addedFiles.length; i++) {
        // get file obj
        var addedFile = addedFiles[i];
        // get done function
        var doneFile = addedFilesHash[addedFile];
        // call done function to upload file to server
        doneFile();
    }
```

We override `accept` and `removedFile` functions. In `accept` function we collect   `file` objects and `done` functions in dict where key is `file` and value is `done` function. Later in time, when we are ready to upload added files, we are iterating all `done` functions for all files in dict `addedFilesHash` which launches upload progress with progress bar and etc.